# Replacement for JDBC-ODBC Bridge

Tags: java, jdbc, odbc, jdbc-odbc

In Java 8 the [JDBC-ODBC-Bridge will be removed](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7176225). The typical error is:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver

Do you know of a possible replacement? I found Easysoft. But this bridge required an additional server which not run inside the Java VM. It is a type 3 driver and not a type 1 driver. Are there other alternatives?

Comment: Which DB server do you access with ODBC. Maybe you find a direct/native JDBC-Driver.

Comment: It is for a wide range of ODBC drivers which have no JDBC equivalent.

Comment: IDS Software / IDS Server is also a type 3 solution, but I believe it hasn't been actively developed for the last 5 or 6 years.

Comment: If anyone is looking for an alternative to the JDBC-ODBC Bridge for manipulating Microsoft Access databases, see the related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390).

Comment: My employer, OpenLink Software, makes a [Type 1 solution](http://uda.openlinksw.com/jdbc-odbc-st/). It's fully compatible with Java 8, etc.

Comment: You can use jdbc odbc classes from jre7 also in jre8 - see stackoverflow.com/a/34617075/2110961

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the meantime we have written our own JDBC-ODBC-Bridge based on JNA for our reporting software [i-net Clear-Reports](https://www.inetsoftware.de/products/clear-reports). Currently the driver is not an official product. But if you have interest then you can contact us.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to take the ODBC stuff from the 1.7 JRE and package it up into it's own JAR file.

To do so (this is for Windows 64 but the process should be the same), you'll need to grab the `JdbcOdbc.dll` out of the 1.7 JRE bin and copy it into the 1.8 JRE bin.

Next, extract the contents of the 1.7 JRE's `lib\rt.jar` into another location.  Once extracted, delete everything except

```
sun\
    jdbc\
        odbc\
            *
    security\
        action\
            LoadLibraryAction.class
```

Then create a JAR file with the remaining contents (the root contents of the JAR should be META-INF and sun).  Copy the JAR file into the 1.8 JRE's `lib\ext` folder.

Comment: Is this valid with the license of the Java VM?

Comment: i found the same solution :) - see stackoverflow.com/a/34617075/2110961