# Rebuilding JRE7 jdbc-odbc bridge for Java 8

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, odbc, java-8

Has anyone looked into extracting the jdbc-odbc bridge from an earlier and using it with JRE8 ?

- Is it practical / possible to update / improve it to work with Java 8 ?
- Would it be legal ?

Comment: It’s most probably neither, legal nor practical, as that’s the reason why it’s not being maintained anymore. Everyone who tried the MS Office drivers in 64 Bit environments will be happy getting rid of it. Have you tried a genuine JDBC driver for your database? What are you missing?

Comment: I've now taken a look at the source code available at http://jdk-source-code.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jdk5.0_src/j2se/src/share/classes/sun/jdbc/odbc/ and it IS possible to rebuild and to get it working well enough for my own application by adding functions for some extended interfaces and killing a lot of multi character-set support. I'm very concerned abot legality though !

Comment: @Doug - it'd probably be hard for programmers here to answer your question in regards to legality.  As far as I can tell, [this](http://jdk-source-code.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jdk5.0_src/JavaResearchLicense.txt) is the license provided with the source link you've given us.  Unfortunately, it's likely you'd need to get a lawyer to tell you whether it's legal or not.  It'd probably depend on what you're doing with it (e.g. selling it).  FWIW, I did find this text in the license: `COMMERCIAL USE AND DISTRIBUTION OF TECHNOLOGY AND
MODIFICATIONS IS PERMITTED ONLY UNDER A SUN COMMERCIAL
LICENSE.`

Comment: Legality aside, the process for copying the JDBC-ODBC components from Java 7 into Java 8 is described in another answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32825016/2144390).

Comment: You can use jdbc odbc classes from jre7 also in jre8 - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/34617075/2110961

Comment: As @GordThompson noted it can be done, but for me it wasn't the solution in the end as the bridge does not support UTF-8: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6345277

Answer (score 2):

While this doesn't exactly answer your question, I was hunting for a free JDBC driver for Access, and found [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html). I had success with this particular driver as a replacement while using SquirrelSQL with Access.  Seeing as how your question is tagged [ms-access](/questions/tagged/ms-access), perhaps this might be an acceptable replacement for you.

Answer (score 0):

Questions of this portation's legality aside, Sun's and Oracle's [official positions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html) have long been that --

> the [JVM-bundled] JDBC-ODBC Bridge should be considered a transitional solution [...] Oracle does not support the JDBC-ODBC Bridge.

However, my employer, [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), has produced enterprise-grade commercial Type 1 Bridges between JDBC and ODBC since Java 1.0, and these are fully compatible with the current Java 8 and any ODBC standard-compliant driver, including Microsoft's ODBC driver for Access.  You can learn more here --

- [Single-Tier JDBC-ODBC Bridge Driver](http://uda.openlinksw.com/jdbc-odbc-st/) -- a JDBC driver for ODBC data sources
- [Single-Tier ODBC-JDBC Bridge Driver](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-jdbc-st/) -- an ODBC driver for JDBC data sources