# How to connect to an ODBC data source from Spring Boot?

Tags: java, jdbc, odbc, openedge

I am developing a Spring Boot application that polls data from a legacy ODBC data source and inserts it into a MS SQL Server database.

[image]

I need to connect to DSN that is using Progress OpenEdge driver.

My R&D code to connect to DSN looks like this:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class JdbcDemo
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            String query = "SELECT Name,Description,Qty,Cost FROM Stock";

            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:DSN_Name");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next())
            {
                String name = rs.getString("Name");
                String desc = rs.getString("Description");
                int qty = rs.getInt("Qty");
                float cost = rs.getFloat("Cost");
                System.out.println(name + ", " + desc + "\t: " + qty + "\t@ $" + cost);
            }
            con.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```

But it throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver error when run. I did some Googling and found this is no longer supported. How can then I connect to this ODBC data source? I am using Java 17.

Comment: This is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19741242/2851311

Comment: @hfontanez It tells that I need specific ODBC driver. Is there no other way ?

Comment: This is the only way I know of.

Comment: Other duplicate: [Replacement for JDBC-ODBC Bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358217/replacement-for-jdbc-odbc-bridge). That said, it would make more sense to use the [Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc) to connect to SQL Server, and the Progress [OpenEdge JDBC driver](https://www.progress.com/jdbc/openedge) for OpenEdge. (As an aside, it is very confusing that in one sentence you say you want to connect to a MS SQL Server database and in another sentence that you want to connect to Progress OpenEdge.)

Answer (score 1):

> java.lang.classnotfoundexception sun.jdbc.odbc.jdbcodbcdriver
> exception comes in Java 8 because it has removed the JDBC ODBC bridge
> driver class "sun.jdbc.odbc.jdbcodbcdriver" from JDK and JRE. This
> class is required to connect any database using Object database
> connectivity driver e.g. Microsoft Access, but unfortunately, you
> cannot use it from JDK 8 onward. In order to solve this error, just
> use the **Jackcess library or a commercial driver like HXTT**. Normally,
> in pre-Java 8 world, java.lang.classnotfoundexception
> sun.jdbc.odbc.jdbcodbcdriver error comes when you try to connect to
> the Microsoft Access database from Java using JDBC and JDBC ODBC
> bridge driver is not available in the classpath.
>
> Read more:
> https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/07/how-to-solve-javalangclassnotfoundexception-sun.jdbc.odbc.jdbcodbcdriver.html#ixzz7TTDxvBZp

We can still use JDBC-ODBC Bridge in Java 8 (Java 17 not tested) too, we can always pull the driver from JDK 7: [Removal of JDBC ODBC bridge in java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229072/removal-of-jdbc-odbc-bridge-in-java-8/)